# Regular Expression to replace CGRectMake

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift3, xcode8

As CGRectMake is not available in swift 3.0 and migrator did not convert it i need to manually replace it and it is used more than 300 times in my code so can anyone help me in this to develop regular expression so i can find and replace code. What i want to do is to convert

CGRectMake(a,a,a,a) here a is some value.

to

CGRect(x: a, y: a, w: a, h: a)

Comment: Check my following answer

Comment: Hi Parth, can you submit a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com with your project attached (preferably in the state before you migrated to swift 3)? The Swift 3 migrator should convert it for you and we would like to take a look and see what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT - With Regex:

```
CGRectMake\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([a-z|0-9|.|A-Z]*)\)
```

and replace with

```
CGRect\(x:\1, y:\2, width:\3, height:\4\)
```

Using regex we can not get the value of x,y,width,height dynamically.

So Alternative solution to above is,

- Replace all the `CGRectMake(` with
  `appdelegateobject.CGRectMakeWrapper("`
- At the end add `"` only.

Means in your case you will replace `CGRectMake(a,a,a,a)` to `appdelegateobject.CGRectMakeWrapper("a,a,a,a"`

where `appdelegateobject` is the `appdelegate` shared instance object where you will define `CGRectMakeWrapper` function having `string` `parameter` as shown below :

```
func CGRectMakeWrapper(str: String) -> CGRect {

    var rect = CGRectZero

    if(str.characters.count > 0)
    {
        var arr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

        if(arr.count == 4)
        {
            rect = CGRect(x: CGFloat((arr[0] as NSString).doubleValue), y: CGFloat((arr[1] as NSString).doubleValue), width: CGFloat((arr[2] as NSString).doubleValue), height: CGFloat((arr[3] as NSString).doubleValue))
        }

    }



    return rect
}

var rect = "10.0,10.0,100,100" //String


var rect1 = CGRectMakeWrapper(rect)  //CGRect
```

I have shown sample string as rect and passed to CGRectMakeWrapper function which will return a rect. You can define this CGRectMakeWrapper function in common class which is accessible to all classes(e.g Appdelegate file).

Answer (score 4):

Find by this:

```
CGRectMake\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)\)
```

and Replace by this:

```
CGRect\(x:\1, y:\2, w:\3, h:\4\)
```

Tried it in notepad++

Comment: Would you please accept it as answer , if it works ?

Comment: it's not working for this type in xcode

CGRectMake(a,a,a,a)   
Function_Name()

as it's checking for the last ) "Closing bracket".

Please find my updated Answer which is tested and working for most cases which you will need.

Answer (score 0):

I have one different way to solve this problem.

> Step 1

In the following line

```
CGRectMake(a,a,a,a)
```

Just replace `CGRectMake` with `CGRectMakeCustom` so all will look like

```
CGRectMakeCustom(a,a,a,a)
```

> Step 2

Create new Global function in the project 
 as follows

```
func CGRectMakeCustom(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double) -> CGRect
    {
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }
```

In this way it will be easy for you to start woking on Swift3

Comment: This is a cool hack. I am already using this but i want to do it with regular expression. Thanx anyway.

Comment: For regular expression @svrushal answer is best uptill now

Answer (score -1):

You can change mode to regular expression while searching and search for:

`CGRectMake\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)\)`

which should be replaced by

`CGRect\(x:\1, y:\2, w:\3, h:\4\)`

Comment: it's not working for this type in xcode CGRectMake(a,a,a,a) Function_Name() as it's checking for the last ) "Closing bracket". Please find my updated Answer which is tested and working for most cases which you will need.